# Which data has changed when editing a model instance in the admin site

Tags: django, django-admin

**Django 3.1.5**

When in the admin site an instance of a model is edited, is there any way to find out
which data has changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django admin saves Log entry

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry

log = LogEntry.objects.all()  # all admin logs
```

More about logs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#logentry-objects